# How to shut a Win app from another app without reboot?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++, win32-process

Hi I want to make a small test window app that can force IE to save its data and shutdown upon a button click and restart with same tabs when another button is clicked??
I am fairly new to Win32 programming can anyone help me out here.?? 
Any leads will be appriciated??

Comment: Depending on what OS version you're targeting, you might be able to use the Restart Manager.  I don't know whether IE supports Restart Manager or not, but it would be worth a try.

Comment: I don't want to let he PC reboot in the whole process.. Target OS Win7

Comment: That's what the Restart Manager is for, to allow you to avoid reboots.  The Restart Manager is included in Windows 7.

Comment: I've never seen IE do this correctly, let alone an external app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find one of each browser class with EnumChildWindows then you save the text(current link) of each one, and send a WM_CLOSE message to the program, if you debug the IE you'll probably see a CALL to the function to open a new window, when you find it, you can call it again and with the new browser class you put the text you got from the one that was opened

Comment: Thanks, Can u help a bit more... Thats what i have been thinking.. but i dunno how to do that.. been spending all my time on this.. But i am fairly new to Win32 APi.. will be good help if u can provide some eg or something..